# BQ import succeeded despite SocketTimeoutException?

Tags: google-bigquery

In some (rare) cases BQ import API call (GAE java) raises SocketTimeoutException.

```
java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Timeout while fetching URL: https://www.googleapis.com/bigquery/v2/projects/{projectId}/jobs
```

Despite the exception it looks like data are successfully imported into BQ table. The problem is the "import" task is restarted (due to exception)-> causing duplicates.

Kind regards,
sasa

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are worried about retrying an import that appeared to fail because of a network error, you can pass a job id along with the load job, in which case you'll be able to look up the status of the job before retrying.

Comment: FYI, same problem different exception (no network error): 

Uncaught exception from servlet
com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 503 OK
{
  "code" : 503,
  "errors" : [ {
    "domain" : "global",
    "message" : "Backend Error",
    "reason" : "backendError"
  } ],
  "message" : "Backend Error"
}